# Airport transit US to Asia

Tags: usa, canada, airports

I am from Canada. My flight will depart from Toronto to Chicago, United States, then Chicago to Asia. Do I need some kind of US transit visa to transfer airplanes? Or transiting to a different airport?

Comment: Your citizenship is what matters. It will be the same as if you wanted to fly to Florida for a few days. There is a reason those flights are cheaper and it isn't just because they might deplane you with extreme prejudice,

Answer (score 2):

> Citizens of Canada and Bermuda do not require visas to transit the United States.

Source: [U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html)